# Removing duplicate key-value pairs in a map with values being in a list

Tags: java, collections

Below is my code to detect abbreviations and their long forms. The code loops over a line in a document, loops over each word of that line and identifies an acronym candidate. It then again loops over each line of the document to find an appropriate long form for the abbreviation. My issue is if an acronym occurs multiple times in a document my output contains multiple instances of it. I just want to print an acronym only once with all its possible long forms. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Workspace\\resource\\SampleSentences.txt"));
        String str=null;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String matchingLongForm;
        List <String> matchingLongForms = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        List <String> shortForm = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        Map<String, List<String>> abbreviationPairs = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


        try
        {
            while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
                lines.add(str);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);




        // document wide search for abbreviation long form and identifying several appropriate matches
        for (String line : linesArray){
            for (String word : (Tokenizer.getTokenizer().tokenize(line))){
                if (isValidShortForm(word)){
                    for (int i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++){
                        matchingLongForm = extractBestLongForm(word, linesArray[i]);
                        //shortForm.add(word);
                        if (matchingLongForm != null && !(matchingLongForms.contains(matchingLongForm))){
                            matchingLongForms.add(matchingLongForm);

                            //System.out.println(matchingLongForm);
                            abbreviationPairs.put(word, matchingLongForms);
                            //matchingLongForms.clear();
                        }
                    } 

                    if (abbreviationPairs != null){
                        //for(abbreviationPairs.)
                        System.out.println("Abbreviation Pair:" + "\t" + abbreviationPairs);
                        abbreviationPairs.clear();
                        matchingLongForms.clear();
                        //System.out.println("Abbreviation Pair:" + "\t" + abbreviationPairsNew);
                    }


                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the current output:

```
Abbreviation Pair:  {GLBA=[Gramm Leach Bliley act]} 
Abbreviation Pair:  {NCUA=[National credit union administration]} 
Abbreviation Pair:  {FFIEC=[Federal Financial Institutions Examination Council]}
Abbreviation Pair:  {CFR=[comments for the Report]} 
Abbreviation Pair:  {CFR=[comments for the Report]} 
Abbreviation Pair:  {CFR=[comments for the Report]} 
Abbreviation Pair:  {CFR=[comments for the Report]} 
Abbreviation Pair:  {OFAC=[Office of Foreign Assets Control]}
```

Comment: Is `Map<String, Set<String>> abbreviationPairs` an option?

Comment: Note the existence of [`Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)). You’re wasting your time by reinventing the wheel… Further, you can simply write `for (String line : lines){ …` without copying the contents of the `List` into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a key value pair for abbreviation and text. So you should use Map. 
A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

The Problem is in the position of the output and not in the map.
You try to output in the loop, so the Map is shown multiple time.

Move the code outside the loop:

```
if (abbreviationPairs != null){
     //for(abbreviationPairs.)
     System.out.println("Abbreviation Pair:" + "\t" + abbreviationPairs);
     abbreviationPairs.clear();
     matchingLongForms.clear();
     //System.out.println("Abbreviation Pair:" + "\t" + abbreviationPairsNew);
}
```

Comment: It’s more the fact that the map is cleared in each loop iteration that makes detecting duplicate keys impossible. But in either case, moving the printing code out of the loop is the right solution. Care must be taken to create a new list for `matchingLongForms` for each mapping. The `clear()` calls become obsolete then.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used a combination of your answers. Moved the printing code outside the loop plus each time I was creating a new list for matchingLongForms.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `java.util.Set` to store your matching short forms and long forms. From the javadoc of the class:

> ... If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements...

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the solution**

*Thanks to code_angel and Holger*

Move the printing code outside the loop and create a new list for every matchingLongForm.

```
for (String line : linesArray){
        for (String word : (Tokenizer.getTokenizer().tokenize(line))){
            if (isValidShortForm(word)){
                for (int i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++){
                    matchingLongForm = extractBestLongForm(word, linesArray[i]);
                    List <String> matchingLongForms = new ArrayList<String>() ;
                    if (matchingLongForm != null && !(matchingLongForms.contains(matchingLongForm))&& !(abbreviationPairs.containsKey(word))){
                        matchingLongForms.add(matchingLongForm);
                        //System.out.println(matchingLongForm);
                        abbreviationPairs.put(word, matchingLongForms);
                        //matchingLongForms.clear();
                    }
                } 

            }
        }
    }
    if (abbreviationPairs != null){
        System.out.println("Abbreviation Pair:" + "\t" + abbreviationPairs);
        //abbreviationPairs.clear();
        //matchingLongForms.clear();

    }

}
```

**The new output:**

```
Abbreviation Pair:  {NCUA=[National credit union administration], FFIEC=[Federal Financial Institutions Examination Council], OFAC=[Office of Foreign Assets Control], MSSP=[Managed Security Service Providers], IS=[Information Systems], SLA=[Service level agreements], CFR=[comments for the Report], MIS=[Management Information Systems], IDS=[Intrusion detection systems], TSP=[Technology Service Providers], RFI=[risk that FIs], EIC=[Examples of in the cloud], TIER=[The institution should ensure], BCP=[Business continuity planning], GLBA=[Gramm Leach Bliley act], III=[It is important], FI=[Financial Institutions], RFP=[Request for proposal]}
```